# В чем ошибка запроса MySql

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь сделать вычисление ближайших точек по координатам:

```
SELECT (
 (
  ACOS(
   SIN(
    49.83555603027 * PI() / 180
   ) * SIN(
    c.lat * PI() / 180
   ) + COS(
    49.83555603027 * PI() / 180
   ) * COS(
    c.lat * PI() / 180
   ) * COS(
    (
     36.68638992310 – c.lng
    ) * PI() / 180
   )
  ) * 180 / PI()
 ) * 60 * 1.1515
) AS `distance`
FROM `tbl_city` c
HAVING `distance`<=’100’ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Получаю ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– c.lng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM tbl_city at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас вместо минуса (`-`) стоит тире (`–`), и кавычки вокруг цифры `100`.

вот так работает (только условие я расширил, чтобы координаты, укладывающиеся в него, не подбирать):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369a4/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table tbl_city (lat int, lng int);
insert into tbl_city values (10, 10), (20, 20);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (
  (
    ACOS(
      SIN(
        49.83555603027 * PI() / 180
      ) * SIN(
        c.lat * PI() / 180
      ) + COS(
        49.83555603027 * PI() / 180
      ) * COS(
        c.lat * PI() / 180
      ) * COS(
        (
          36.68638992310 - c.lng
        ) * PI() / 180
      )
    ) * 180 / PI()
  ) * 60 * 1.1515
) AS `distance`
FROM `tbl_city` c
HAVING `distance`<=10000
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369a4/3/0)**:

```
|           distance |
|--------------------|
| 2256.1324840016114 |
| 3147.3906530938702 |
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас две ошибки `– c.lng` там не минус, а видимо, тире (`Alt0150`). А, во вторых, `HAVING distance<=’100’` -  уберите кавычки вокруг 100